# React and sequelize error handling to show message from the frontend

Tags: exception, react-router

I am using React with axios to the frontend and once I am sending the post request I get the folowing error "Unhandled rejection SequelizeUniqueConstraintError: Validation error", but at the frontend it is not getting any problem.
How could I handling this at the frontend to show the message for the user?

```
            <Button
              type='submit'
              variant='contained'
              color='primary'
            size='large'
              onClick={() => {
                axios
                  .post(
                    `http://${config.host}:${config.port}/apartment`,
                    {
                      apartment_id: apartment_id,
                      apartment_block_id: selected_tower,
                      apartment_block_name:
                        apartment_data.apartment_block_name,
                      apartment_floor: apartment_floor,
                      apartment_size: selected_apartment_data,
                      apartment_parking_id: selected_apartment_data,
                    },
                  )
                  .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                  })
                  .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                  });
              }}
            >
              Cadastrar
            </Button>
```